# AngularJs ng-if comparing dates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am looking to compare two dates in ng-if this is what my jade file looks like.

```
li.list-group-item(ng-if="app.Segments[0].StartDate.getTime() > date.getTime()")
    div.row
        div.col-xs-12
            span
                i.fa.fa-plus-square
```

This code will hopefully add an li to my ui if the startdate of the first segment is after today.

```
$scope.date = new Date();
$scope.app = {
    Segments: [{
       StartDate: 2014-11-15T04:00:00.000Z
       EndDate: 2014-11-20T04:00:00.000Z
    },
    {
        StartDate: 2014-11-21T04:00:00.000Z
        EndDate: 2014-11-25T04:00:00.000Z
    }]

}
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: I'm assuming those segments are actually strings?

Comment: They are stored as date objects in a mongoDB and pulled in my controller. I was just trying to show how the data looked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If they're date object just compare them directly without `.getTime()`

```
$scope.date2005 = new Date('2005/01/01');
$scope.date2006 = new Date('2006-01-01T04:00:00.000Z');
```

```
<div ng-if="date2005 > date2006">date2005 > date2006</div> <!-- won't show -->
<div ng-if="date2006 > date2005">date2006 > date2005</div> <!-- will show -->
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fNB11U6KmFszdV3lMAPJ?p=preview

Comment: okay that definitely answered my question. I think my problem is that the date objects coming from mongo are coming back as strings and not as objects but that may be because it was test data I entered manually and did it wrong.

Comment: @DaltonShehan You can just make it into a new date object with the string like this: `new Date('2006-01-01T04:00:00.000Z')`

Comment: Right that what I ended up doing thanks for the help.

Comment: @DaltonShehan you can compare strings with inequalities, and you should get the same result as a comparison of a date with an inequality if the string is formatted the same for both dates.

Answer (score 8):

Angular can directly compare date if they are well formated:

view

```
li.list-group-item(ng-if="app.Segments[0].StartDate > now")
```

controller

```
$scope.now = new Date();
$scope.now.toISOString();
```